# Laravel 7 redirects to login Page

Tags: php, laravel

I have a code in HomeController.php in the Laravel framework, but I could not access the index/homepage it redirects to the login page. what is the blunder I am committing?

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Show the application dashboard.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
     */
    public function index()
    {
        $users = User::get();
        return view('home', compact('users'));
    }

    public function user($id){
        $user = User::find($id);
        return view('user', compact('user'));
    }

    public function ajax(Request $request){
        $user = User::find($request->user_id);
        $response = auth()->user()->toggleFollow($user);
        return response()->json(['success'=> $response]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Is the user already authenticated? if not, the middleware, your assigning in the constructor might cause the redirect.

Comment: In which file should I check I am new to Laravel and PHP?

Comment: did you login? the auth middleware redirects anyone who isn't logged in/authenticated to the login page

Comment: Let me try wait a minute.

Comment: Let me rephrase my question: Do you use a login? If not, delete your constructor in the `HomeController`

Comment: Maybe read about [authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authentication) and [middleware](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/middleware) in the Laravel documentation

Comment: Logging in solved the issue. Thanks.

Comment: Please write the solution other might find helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is simple. In the `__construct()` method, you specified that every function under this controller must use the `auth` `middleware`. This will redirect to `login` page is the user is not logged in.

There are a number of ways to work around this, the first being to remove the `__construct` entirely. However, this is not so recommended.

Another would be to add an `except()` function

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->middleware('auth')->except('index');
}
```

This will allow the condition to apply anywhere else other than the `index` function.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the code you posted, the homepage route is protected by the 'auth' middleware, which means users have to login to access the resource page (Home page), so you should first login and then it will direct you to the intended page. If you don't want the page to be protected, then you could either remove the `$this->middleware('auth')` in your constructor, or you could put the index() function separately in a different Controller file and leave it unprotected

Answer (score 0):

you can also control it in the [routes (routes/web.php)](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/authentication#protecting-routes).

Or as already mentioned with middleware: [Assigning Middleware To Routes](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/middleware#assigning-middleware-to-routes)

Answer (score 0):

[Route Group](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/routing#route-group-middleware)

Use route grouping in your web.php file

This way you can determine middleware for specific routes, you can also use grouping inside route group also

And don't use middleware in controller, use it in web.php so you can have a proper idea that how many routes are using middleware